# Navigation Dots not changing to the correct image

Tags: jquery, slider

In my slider I have navigation dots that is suppose to display the correct image when clicked, but when I click my dots, a dot disappears and the dot that I clicked doesn't become active and if I click again my dots move to the left and if I click again my dots disappear completely.

I don't know where I went wrong.
My HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 slider-wrapper">
<div class="banner_wrapper active_banner" style="opacity: 1; left: 0%;">
  <img class="bgwidth" src="http://i.imgur.com/YW5Y1YX.jpg">
</div>
<div class="banner_wrapper inactive_banner" style="opacity: 0; left: 100%;">
  <img class="bgwidth" src="http://i.imgur.com/vFEg6ef.jpg">
</div>
<div class="banner_wrapper inactive_banner" style="opacity: 0; left: -100%;">
  <img class="bgwidth" src="http://i.imgur.com/cEcFlSA.jpg">
</div>

<div class="banner-nav-wrapper">
  <a class="active_inside" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <span></span>
  </a>
  <a class="inactive_inside" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <span></span>
  </a>
  <a class="inactive_inside" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <span></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

My css

```
html{
background: black;
}

.banner_wrapper img{
position: absolute;
}

.banner-nav-wrapper {
  left: 46%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
}

.banner-nav-wrapper a{
  display:block;
  width:13px;
  height:14px;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/J8UrHgn.png) top left no-repeat;
  float:left;
  margin:0 5px 0 0;
}
.banner-nav-wrapper a.active_inside span{
  display:block !important;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/NxoSIbh.png) top left no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.banner-nav-wrapper a.inactive_inside span{
  display:block !important;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/J8UrHgn.png) top left no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.banner-nav-wrapper a span{
  display:none;   
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/NxoSIbh.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

My JS

```
$(".banner-nav-wrapper a").click(function(){
  if($(".active_inside").next(".banner_wrapper").length < 1){
      $(".banner_wrapper").eq(0).animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":1}, 500,function(){
        $(this).addClass("active_inside").removeClass("inactive_inside");
      });
  }else{
      $(".active_inside").next().animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":1}, 500,function(){
        $(this).addClass("active_inside").removeClass("inactive_inside");
      });
  }




  if($(".active_inside").prev().length < 1){
    $(".banner_wrapper").eq($(".banner_wrapper").length-1).animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":1}, 500,function(){
      $(this).addClass("active_inside").removeClass("inactive_inside");
    });
  }else{
    $(".active_inside").prev().animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":1}, 500,function(){
      $(this).addClass("active_inside").removeClass("inactive_inside");
    });
  }

  $(".active_inside").animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":0}, 500,function(){
    $(this).addClass("inactive_inside").removeClass("active_inside"); 
  });
});
```

And here is a Demo: [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoKGaY)

Comment: Refer http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Extremely-Simple-jQuery-Slidershow-Plugin-Dot-Slider/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You need to calculate index of next active element first and then apply `active_inside` to it and remove from others.

You need to show / hide `banner_wrapper` elements as per clicked `a` element from `banner-nav-wrapper`

```
$(function(){
$(".banner-nav-wrapper a").click(function(){
  //calculate next active element index.
  var nextIndex = $(this).index();

  //remove active_inside from current active element
  $(".active_inside").addClass("inactive_inside").removeClass("active_inside");

  //apply active_inside to next active element
  $(this).animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":1}, 500,function(){
     $(this).addClass("active_inside").removeClass("inactive_inside");
  });

  //hide currently visible 'banner_wrapper' element and show next 'banner_wrapper'
  // on the basis of next index calculated.
  $('.banner_wrapper:visible').animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":0}, 500,function(){
     $('.banner_wrapper:eq('+nextIndex+')').animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":1}, 500,function(){
     });
  }); 
});
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fx4bLujq/9/)**

Comment: That was almost perfect but what if the user clicked the 3rd dot?